# er diagram showing relations between attributes

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram, erd

I'm looking for **free** tool for generating ER diagram. I now there are a lot of stuff I can find them in google, but I need something specific and can't it find.

The tool should generate ER diagrams showing relations between attributes like in below image. Note that this diagram shows phisical relation **table1.attributeX <----> table2.attributeY**

[image]

**Note: I am not asking for tools that generate diagrams like these. This diagrams doesn't explicit show relations between attrobutes.**

[image]
<sub>(source: [philblock.info](http://www.philblock.info/hitkb/_images/erd-example2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is a free tool that generates diagrams showing relations between attributes. That is, there is a relationship line drawn from the primary key column to the foreign key column. Here is an [example diagram](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/images/diagram.png): [image: SchemaCrawler Diagram]

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's the style MS Access uses in their relationships dialog/overview. It is not the standard so I don't think there a lot of tools will support that kind of notation. I suggest to take a look at ms access. The alternative? I know that in [DeZign for Databases](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/index.html) you can drag the relationship line on a side of the entity box. This way you can manually point it to the correct attribute. Not sure if you want that.